# Fragment's reference to fragmentPagerAdapter is null

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback, android-viewpager, android-lifecycle

So I've got 5 (6?) fragments in a ViewPager, they all interact with each other using callbacks through the Activity to get information from one another.  I was getting some problems because they needed to be started in a particular order, and some seemed to be starting before others were ready regardless of what I did, so I implemented a callback for all the fragments to initialize themselves only once all of them were ready:

```
@Override
public void notifyReady() {
    boolean settingsReady = false;
    boolean fileReady = false;
    boolean recordTableReady = false;
    boolean chartReady = false;
    boolean pieChartReady = false;

    if (settingsFragment != null)
        settingsReady = settingsFragment.isReady();

    if (fileFragment != null)
        fileReady = fileFragment.isReady();

    if (recordTableFragment != null)
        recordTableReady = recordTableFragment.isReady();

    if (chartFragment != null)
        chartReady = chartFragment.isReady();

    if (pieChartFragment != null)
        pieChartReady = pieChartFragment.isReady();

    boolean allReady = settingsReady & fileReady & recordTableReady & chartReady & pieChartReady;

    if (allReady) {
        settingsFragment.initialize();
        fileFragment.initialize();
        recordTableFragment.initialize();
        chartFragment.initialize();
        pieChartFragment.initialize();
    }
```

I put the interface implementation in my FragmentPagerAdapter, since that's where I read I should be initializing fragments anyway:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
  switch(pos) {
    case 0:
      return new SettingsFragment();
    case 1:
      return new FileFragment();
    case 2:
      return new OracleFragment();  // No implementation yet
    case 3:
      return new RecordTableFragment();
    case 4:
      return new ChartFragment();
    case 5:
      return new PieChartFragment();
    default:
      return null; // BAD
  }
}
```

Alongside the initialization of the callback interface to the FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
  Fragment createdFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);

  switch (position) {
    case 0:
      settingsFragment = (SettingsFragment) createdFragment;
      settingsFragment.setNotificationListener(this);
      break;
    case 1:
      fileFragment = (FileFragment) createdFragment;
      fileFragment.setNotificationListener(this);
      break;
    case 2:
      oracleFragment = (OracleFragment) createdFragment;
      //oracleFragment.setNotificationListener(this); (This fragment has no implementation yet)
      break;
    case 3:
      recordTableFragment = (RecordTableFragment) createdFragment;
      recordTableFragment.setNotificationListener(this);
      break;
    case 4:
      chartFragment = (ChartFragment) createdFragment;
      chartFragment.setNotificationListener(this);
      break;
    case 5:
      pieChartFragment = (PieChartFragment) createdFragment;
      pieChartFragment.setNotificationListener(this);
      break;
  }
  return createdFragment;
}
```

And I had my fragments call:

```
public void setNotificationListener(FragmentNotifier fragmentNotifier) {
    this.fragmentNotifier = fragmentNotifier;
}
```

for the FragmentPagerAdapter to set itself as the interface object, and

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    ready = true;
    fragmentNotifier.notifyReady();
}
```

For initialization.  This works incredibly well at first, but fragmentNotifier becomes null after coming back to the activity after a while, and the fragments' onStart() is called when the activity starts up again, producing a NullPointerException.  Why is it becoming null?  Other fields like the Fragment's reference to the Activity and the interface provided by it aren't null at this point in the execution, I've checked with a debugger, but fragmentNotifier IS!  Why?!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to debug your code and find out where is it going wrong, but I'll give you a better solution.

I've been through this in the past and I've realized that the best way to find and store callbacks defined in your Activity is inside your Fragments. So instead of using setters, use this in your Fragments:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity){

    if (activity instanceof FragmentNotifier)
        mFragmentNotifier  = (FragmentNotifier) activity;
    else throw new IllegalAccessException("Activity must implement the FragmentNotifier interface");

}
```

This will ensure that you'll have a reference to your Activity. And add this to avoid leaking the reference:

```
@Override
public void onDetach(){
    mFragmentNotifier = null;
}
```